# Format date with moment js library

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to use moment js library in my GWT JSNI code:

```
public native String momentNow(String date) /*-{
    $wnd.console.log("Date: " + date);
    return $wnd.moment("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z", date).format();
}-*/;
```

With a example input: `2014-02-04 07:47 +0800`

But, what the method returns is "Invalid date" String. What could be wrong in my code?

Comment: First of all, you need `ZZ`, not `Z`. Secondly, this is a sign of a bigger problem, since I don't think even having `ZZ` works.

Comment: What were you trying to do? This seems interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... this is odd:

This works:

```
moment("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ZZ", moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ZZ"))
moment("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ZZ", "2014-02-04 07:47 +0800")
+moment("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ZZ", "2014-02-04 07:47 +0800")
```

But this doesn't work:

```
moment(
        "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ZZ", 
        moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ZZ")
      ).format()
```

And this works:

```
moment( +moment("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ZZ", "2014-02-04 07:47 +0800") ).format()
```

So is that a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You have the parameters in the wrong order.  Per [the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), the format string should be passed as the *second* parameter.

```
moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z").format()
```

However, since this format is one of the default ISO strings [listed here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), you can just omit it.

```
moment(date).format()
```